# Code Error with a Confirmation Candle on BB %B indicator

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api, pine-script-v4

I have wrote this study code for Pine Script Ver.4 but I'm stuck on the Alertcondition where I want it to plot and send alerts to me if the below conditions meet using BB %B:

1. Green candle crossover BB %B Zero value and confirmed with a 2nd green candle.
2. Red candle crossunder BB %B 1.0 value and confirmed with a 2nd red candle.

```
//@version=4
study("CGBT Alert", overlay=true)

// Bollinger Band Settings
length = input(20, minval=1)
mult = input(2.0, minval=0.001, maxval=50)
src = close  // source for BB calculation (close, open, high, low)


// Bollinger Band Calculation 
bb_upper = sma(src, length) + mult * stdev(src, length)  // upper band calculation 
bb_lower = sma(src, length) - mult * stdev(src, length)  // lower band calculation 


 // BB %B Calculation 
bb_percB = (src - bb_lower)/ (bb_upper - bb_lower)*100


 // Alert Conditions 
alertcondition(crossunder(bb_percB[2], 0), title='BB %B Cross Under 0', message='BB %B Cross Under 0')




 // Plotting the Indicators 
plot(bb_upper, color=#FF0000 , linewidth=2 , title="Upper Band")   // Red Line for Upper Band  
plot(bb_lower, color=#00FF00 , linewidth=2 , title="Lower Band")   // Green Line for Lower Band  
plotshape(crossover(bb_percB[2], 0), style=shape.triangleup , color=color.green , location=location.belowbar , size=size.small )
```

I created a code to plot the arrow up on crossing but not with a confirmed candle color

Comment: So, what have you tried except asking chatGPT?

Comment: I tried going through the Pine Script documentations but I couldn't get the code where to combine BB %B with a confirmation candle!! probable cuz my code Ver. is 4 and Pine Script is on 5

Comment: It has nothing to do with pinescript version. It is just simple maths. You can assume a candle is green if `close > open`.

Comment: I added these 2 lines before: greenCandle = (close > open)
redCandle = (close < open) and I tried using greenCandle in the plot and alertcondition but it returns with 'Too much arguments'

Answer (score 0):

```
//@version=4
study("CGBT Alert", overlay=true)

// Bollinger Band Settings
length = input(20, minval=1)
mult = input(2.0, minval=0.001, maxval=50)
src = close  // source for BB calculation (close, open, high, low)


// Bollinger Band Calculation 
bb_upper = sma(src, length) + mult * stdev(src, length)  // upper band calculation 
bb_lower = sma(src, length) - mult * stdev(src, length)  // lower band calculation 


 // BB %B Calculation 
bb_percB = (src - bb_lower)/ (bb_upper - bb_lower)*100


 // Alert Conditions 
alertcondition(crossunder(bb_percB[2], 0), title='BB %B Cross Under 0', message='BB %B Cross Under 0')




 // Plotting the Indicators 
plot(bb_upper, color=#FF0000 , linewidth=2 , title="Upper Band")   // Red Line for Upper Band  
plot(bb_lower, color=#00FF00 , linewidth=2 , title="Lower Band")   // Green Line for Lower Band  


//Modified/chnaged below two lines
plotshape(open[2]<close[2] and open[1]<close[1] and crossover(bb_percB[2], 0), style=shape.triangleup , color=color.green , location=location.belowbar , size=size.small )
plotshape(open[2]>close[2] and open[1]>close[1] and crossunder(bb_percB[2], 1), style=shape.triangledown , color=color.red , location=location.abovebar , size=size.small )
```